# How to encode string in react-native?

Tags: react-native, encode

I'm using search api and I need to send string which needs to be encoded.

```
let details = {
                query: query,
                display: 100,
                start: offset
              };
              let formBody = [];
              for (let property in details) {
                let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
                let encodedValue = encodeURI(details[property]);
                formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
              }
              formBody = formBody.join("&");
              const response = await fetch(naverurl, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: postHeaders,
                body: formBody
              });
              await console.log(query, encodeURIComponent(query));
              const text = await response.json();
              await console.log(text);
```

this is my code.
When I send english to query, it works. but Korean(I'm Korean) it's not working.
I'm sure this is encoding issue.
How can I solve this?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally encode twice and it worked! 
If you have problem like me, try encode twice.
I hope it would be help you solve your problem!

Comment: could you show the code?